# Implementation of tableView cellForRowAt with a nested function

Tags: swift, uitableview, swift3, nested-function

In on of the git repositories I found pretty weird implementation of tableView cellForRowAt method.

The method have inside implementation of `configureCell` method. Isn't that wrong ? Let say.. for 1000 cells in table view - it is going to create this method about 1000 thousand times ? Can any one tell me if it is good way in swift or not ? I suppose it is totally wrong.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        func configureVehicleCell(_ object: CustomModel) -> UITableViewCell {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCellTableViewCell

            if object.hasIssues {
                cell.dvirImageView.isHidden = false
            }

            if object.cmv {
                cell.cmvImageView.isHidden = false
            }

            cell.titleLabel.text = object.name
            cell.subtitleLabel.text = object.someName

            cell.tag = Int(object.id)

            return cell
        }

        if lastUsedId == nil {
            return configureCell(objectArray[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row])
        } else {
            if (indexPath as NSIndexPath).section == 0 {

                return configureCell(lastUsed!)
            } else {
                return configureCell(objectsArray[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row])
            }
        }
    }
```

In my opinion it should look like:

```
   override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            if lastUsedId == nil {
                return configureCell(objectArray[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row])
            } else {
                if (indexPath as NSIndexPath).section == 0 {

                    return configureCell(lastUsed!)
                } else {
                    return configureCell(objectsArray[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row])
                }
            }
        } 


func configureVehicleCell(_ object: CustomModel) -> UITableViewCell {
                let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCellTableViewCell

                if object.hasIssues {
                    cell.dvirImageView.isHidden = false
                }

                if object.cmv {
                    cell.cmvImageView.isHidden = false
                }

                cell.titleLabel.text = object.name
                cell.subtitleLabel.text = object.someName

                cell.tag = Int(object.id)

                return cell
            }
```

Comment: And you got a misconception, it's not _going to create this method about 1000 thousand times_: it's just a declarative scope.

Comment: @Cœur Could you link me an article about that behaviour ? I was not able to find anything. Whenever I've created the question in google it through me into completion handler.

Comment: [Nested Functions official doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH10-ID178) (bottom of the page)

Comment: @Cœur Basically are they differences with performance ?

Comment: no performance difference at all if you declare it as `private func`.